# Letter of support - Canada Visa

Tags: visas, canada

I am a student applying for Canada visitor visa. My parents are supporting me financially. Is it mandatory to write the letter of support as an affidavit in the presence of notary public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if I remember correctly.
You just need to take the letter of support to a bank or anywhere that does it to get notarized. It usually doesn't cost much or not at all.